# Prefixed ID without using trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, prefix

Is there a way to have a prefixed ID without using triggers? Currently, we are using triggers for this but it has made known to us yesterday that we are moving to cloud that does not allow triggers. We are not allowed to do this:

```
set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
```

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is about. Perhaps using a myisam table, where the auto_increment field is the 2nd in a multi column index is what you are looking for. Scroll down to myisam notes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: @Shadow we have tables for our web app. and the IDs for each row are prefixed (i.e. ABC-00001). We are able to do this using trigger. This is setup in our dev environment. Now, we are putting it in production which is hosted on the cloud and I was informed recently that they are not allowing triggers for this.

Comment: Then see the link I gave you. Make sure you scroll down to myisam notes.

Comment: @shadow Thank you. Read about it. We are using InnoDB and prefer such as many users will be accessing the tables with different transactions.

Comment: Just split them into prefix and increment - but don't use auto_increment for this.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry. Can you please elaborate? Thanks again.

Comment: So, one column holds the prefix, and another column holds the increment